# Diseño base de datos Jefe, empleado, Tienda

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, diagrama-er

llevo horas pensando y necesito de su ayuda. Tengo tres tablas(Empleado, tienda e Historial) y los requerimientos son:

1. Guardar el historial cuando un empleado es cambiado a una tienda diferente.(con una relacion N:M lo solucioné, todo OK)
2. Un empleado puede convertirse en jefe de una tienda o de dos ( aquí necesito su ayuda, ya que trate de hacer una relacion de 1:M, como pueden ver en la imagen que adjunto)
3. Debo hacer un SELECT y visualizar a todas las tiendas con sus respectivos jefes

Debo hacer otra tabla llamada Jefe? modificar las relaciones?, alguna sugerencia o modificación a mi diseño, Gracias !!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Para qué sirve la llave jefe en la tabla empleado?

Comment: Sirve para convertir a un empleado en jefe y relacionarlo con la Tienda. Creo q lo estoy haciendo mal, justo es el motivo de mi pregunta

Comment: ¡Divide y Gobierna! En la tabla en que registras empleados quita la llave jefe (ser jefe no lo hace menos empleado) crea una tabla de roles (idrol, rolname, opcional roldescripcion) una tabla de asignación actual "posiciones" (idposicion, idempleado, idrol, idtienda) Y, en el historial de asignaciones agregas FK_idrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He visto, al menos a mi parecer, cosas que me han llamado la atención:

Veo que en Tienda no tienes un campo que sea jefe, para hacer referencia después a la clave principal de empleado. En empleado, jefe no hace falta que sea clave primaria, admitirá dos valores: 0 o 1, si es 0 no será jefe, si es 1, sí.

La lógica es la siguiente:

- 1 empleado podrá ser jefe o no.
- 1 empleado que es jefe, podrá tener 1-N tiendas
- y una tienda podrá tener solo 1 empleado jefe.

No hace falta hacer una tabla nueva de jefes, porque un jefe es un empleado, lo que sería redundante.

Te dejo el modelo:

[image: Database Model]

La consulta, se tiene que hacer con join, hay muchas formas de hacer un join, yo te pongo la que a mí me resulta más simple. No sé muy bien cómo querrías mostrar los resultados, yo lo he hecho para que una tabla solo te salga la información de la tienda y del jefe.

```sql
 SELECT  t.*, e.* FROM tienda t, empleado e WHERE e.jefe = 1 AND t.jefe = e.idEmpleado
```

No sé si lo sabes, pero cuando ponemos el nombre de la tabla al lado podemos poner lo que se conoce como un alias para referirnos a esa tabla, en vez de poner tabla.campo, que queda más largo.

Lo que haríamos es:

Selecciona todo de la tabla tienda y todo de la tabla empleado cuando el campo jefe (el que nos dice si es jefe o no) sea 1, es decir, que sea jefe y que el campo jefe de la tabla tienda (en el que guardamos el id del jefe) sea igual al id del empleado.

Con esto:

1. Descartamos los que no sean jefes.
2. Ya tenemos todos los que sí son jefes
3. Cogemos el id del primer jefe, buscamos en el campo jefe de la tabla tienda si coincide, si coincide, lo mostramos, si no coincide, no se muestra.
4. Obtenemos la info de todas las tiendas y la info del jefe de esas tiendas.

Otra cosa que veo, es que en la tabla de Historial, ¿cómo sabes en qué tienda estaba y a cuál se ha cambiado? Yo pondría dos campos más: id_antigua_tienda y id_nueva_tienda (las dos haciendo referencia al idTienda).

Espero que te haya servido.

Comment: Por qué tienda y empleado deben llevar una llave llamada jefe?

Comment: El campo jefe de empleado guardará un 0 o un 1 para saber si es jefe o no (0 no es jefe, 1 sí es jefe), el campo jefe de tienda guardará el id del empleado, quizá debería haberlo llamado idJefe. Con el campo jefe de empleado descartamos todos los que no sea jefes, y con el campo de jefe en tienda, es campo que nos va a servir para relacionar las dos tablas y obtener así la información del empleado.

Comment: @BetaM En la pregunta no se pedía evaluar si había cambios de puesto. Si hubiera distintos tipos de jefe, etc, sí tendría más sentido hacer una nueva tabla con toda es información. Cuando haces el SELECT saldrán todos las tiendas con sus jefes, si sale el mismo jefe en dos tiendas diferentes, es que el jefe está en dos tiendas. Esta solución la he dado por lo que he entendido de la pregunta, vaya, que me puedo equivocar :)

Comment: Cierto, el empleado puede dejar de ser empleado para ser empleado jefe. Se puede saber, aún así, con el campo jefe de empleado. En cualquier momento el empleado puede ser jefe (1) o no serlo (0), y con la consulta que he expuesto, podemos saber de cuántas tiendas es jefe.

Comment: Buena logica !!, lo aplicaré y les coment, gracias.

Comment: @mrgold92 y si quisiera listar todo el personal (empleados y jefe) que labora en una misma tienda?, cual seria la query?

Comment: En ese caso, simplemente: SELECT t.* tienda, e.* FROM tienda t, empleado e WHERE idTienda = [id de la tienda a consultar]